# React component converted to HTML not working as expected only on Gmail

Tags: html, css, reactjs, node.js, gmail

This is my backend nodejs sendEmail():

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer'

const sendEmail = async(email,subject,html) =>{
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host:process.env.HOST,
        service:process.env.SERVICE,
        port:Number(process.env.EMAIL_PORT),
        secure:Boolean(process.env.SECURE),
        auth:{
            user:process.env.EMAIL,
            pass:process.env.PASSWORD
        }
    });
    
    await transporter.sendMail({
        from:process.env.EMAIL,
        to:email,
        subject,
        html
    })

    // console.log("Email sent")
}

export default sendEmail;
```

This is my ReactJS components

This is my HtmlTemplate component which is converted to HTML using const html= ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()

```
import React from "react";

export const HtmlTemplate = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    

        <div
          style={{
            width: "auto",
            margin: "0 auto",
            padding: "0",
            boxSizing: "border-box",
            fontFamily: "Arial, sans-serif",
            lineHeight: "1.6",
            color: "#333",
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            display:'flex',
            flexDirection:'column'
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ padding: "1.5rem", backgroundColor: "white", color: "black", boxSizing: "border-box", textAlign: "center", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", gap: "1.5rem" }}>
            <div>
              You are receiving this email because you signed up at
              <a href="http://localhost:3000" style={{ textDecoration: "underline" }}>
                UpscMax
              </a>
            </div>
            <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", gap: "0.625rem",fontSize:'2rem' }}>
              <a href="http://localhost:3000" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" ,display: "flex",alignItems:'center'}}>
                <img
                  src="https://res.cloudinary.com/duuwrm4bh/image/upload/v1706290685/bj8c3aa8qi0fulz4fwgz.png"
                  alt="UpscMax Logo"
                  style={{ width: "2.5rem", height: "2.5rem" }}
                />
                <p style={{ fontSize: "2.5rem", fontWeight: 600 }}>
                  Upsc<span style={{ color: "red" }}>Max</span>
                </p>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", gap: "1rem", alignItems: "center",backgroundColor:'' }}>
              <p style={{ fontSize: "1.25rem", fontWeight: 900 }}>Daily Update</p>
              <p style={{ fontSize: "1rem" }}>Not a Premium yet? Buy Premium to have the best learning</p>
              <a href="http://localhost:3000" style={{ paddingInline: "0.9375rem", paddingBlock: "0.5rem", backgroundColor: "#1216ed", width: "fit-content", color: "white", borderRadius: "0.25rem", textDecoration: "none" }}>
                Buy Now
              </a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p style={{ textAlign: "left", fontSize: "1.25rem", fontWeight: "bold", margin: "0" }}>Dear Aspirant,</p>
              <p style={{ textAlign: "left", fontSize: "1.5rem", margin: "0" }}>Here is the latest affair for you</p>
            </div>
            <div style={{ textAlign: "left", fontSize: "1.125rem", width: "100%", fontWeight: "medium" }}>
              Your daily current affair <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{title}</span> is available now. Visit
              <span style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
                <a href="http://localhost:3000" style={{ textDecoration: "underline", color: "black" }}>
                  Upsc<span style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}>Max</span>
                </a>
              </span>
              for all the recent updates
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Best regards, Team UPSCMax</p>
          </div>
        </div>

  );
};
```

This is my SendMail component , where I take the title and pass it to the HtmlTemplate Component then convert the component to HTML and send it as email body

```
import { Button, Input } from '@material-tailwind/react'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { HtmlTemplate } from './'
import { useSendDailyMailMutation } from '../slices/emailSlice'
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'


export const SendMail = () => {
const [title, settitle] = useState("")
const[sendMail]=useSendDailyMailMutation()
    const handleChange=(e)=>{
        settitle(e.target.value)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(title)
    }, [title])

    const handleSubmit=async()=>{
        const html= ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<HtmlTemplate title={title}/>)
        console.log(html)
{        const {data,error}=await sendMail({html:html})
        if(data){
          toast.success('Emails send')
          console.log(data)
        }
        else if(error){
          toast.success('Emails not sent')
          console.log("Email error",error)
        }}
        
    }
    
  return (
    <>
    <div className='p-5 bg-blue-gray-900'>
        <Input placeholder='' size='lg' label='Title' color='blue' className='p-3 text-white text-lg' value={title} onChange={(e)=>{handleChange(e)}}/>
        <br/>
        <Button color='blue' onClick={handleSubmit}>Send mail</Button>
    </div>
    <HtmlTemplate title={title}/>

    </>
  )
}
```

Below is the emailSlice.js (Using Redux toolkit)

```
import { apiSlice } from "./apiSlice";

const EMAIL_URL = "/api/email";



export const emailSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    sendDailyMail: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: `${EMAIL_URL}/dailyUpdate`,
        method: "POST",
        body:body
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

export const { 
useSendDailyMailMutation
} = emailSlice;
```

Here are the screenshots of different devices and platform

[Screenshot of Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8WiH.png)

[Screenshot in IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBv9J.jpg)

[Screenshot in ProtonMail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADKDS.png)

As you can see, the screenshots on IOS and ProtonMail are as expected but Gmail is not.
How to solve this problem?

Tried available methods in the react documentation like
`import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server' const htmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)`

Used tools like chatGPT and Bard but no luck.

Looked like the problem is faced only on Gmail android app and website.

Comment: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-flex-direction/ flex-direction is not supported